# Implement JS function with methods in scalajs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scala.js, topojson

I'm trying to create a world map with topojson and d3-geo using scalajs based on the following example: [How-to-create-pure-react-SVG-maps-with-topojson-and-d3-geo](https://zcreativelabs.com/blog/How-to-create-pure-react-SVG-maps-with-topojson-and-d3-geo/)

My biggest issue so far is what I don't understand how I can implement *geoEqualEarth()* and *geoPath()* functions from d3-geo using scala since both of them have a number of methods, for example `const projection = geoEqualEarth().scale(160).translate([ 800 / 2, 450 / 2 ])`. This piece of code suppose to create a projection (which is assumed to be an array of numeric values), and that projection is later used in `geoPath().projection(projection)(d)` to create a proper input string for the `<d>` tag. I'm really confused about how such kind of logic can be implemented in scala and I'm not sure if I can use pure JS in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can implement geoEqualEarth() and geoPath() functions from d3-geo

I assume that what you mean by that is *using* those functions, which are defined in the JavaScript library d3-geo, from Scala.js.

In general, to use JavaScript libraries from Scala.js, you either [define facade types](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/facade-types.html) for the library, or reuse one that is already existing, perhaps through [ScalablyTyped](https://scalablytyped.org/docs/readme.html). How the facades are declared depends mostly on what the API looks like, and how it's supposed to be used.

Just trying to make your example snippets valid, I would aim for

```scala
@js.native
trait Projection extends js.Object {
  def scale(factor: Double): this.type
  def translate(v: js.Tuple2[Double, Double]): this.type
}

@js.native
trait Path extends js.Object {
  def projection(p: Projection): Path
  def apply(obj: js.Any): Something = js.native
}

// import { geoEqualEarth, geoPath } from "d3-geo"
object D3GeoFunctions {
  @js.native
  @JSImport("d3-geo", "geoEqualEarth")
  def geoEqualEarth(): Projection = js.native

  @js.native
  @JSImport("d3-geo", "geoPath")
  def geoPath(): Path = js.native
}
```

although a lot of this is guesswork based on your snippet and skimming the d3-geo readme.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it looks like more or less what I'm trying to do but I'm struggling to properly define facades for these two functions. Based on your example I've tried to define a facade for the Projection like: @js.native
trait Projection extends js.Function1[js.Tuple2[Double,Double],js.Tuple2[Double,Double]] {

  def apply(lonLat:js.Tuple2[Double,Double]): js.Tuple2[Double, Double] = js.native
  def scale(factor: Double): this.type
  def translate(v: js.Tuple2[Int, Int]): this.type

}, but got Uncaught TypeError: $i_d3$002dgeo is undefined

Comment: Thanks again, I modified this example a little bit and it worked for me